Demon possessed girl in a correctional institution
The movie is about a girl, who is living with two other girls in something like a correctional institution. Well... it's not really an institution, it's more like a house where a man mentors the girls on how to get rid of their detrimental habits, he's something like a father to them I guess. Anyways, she - the heroine, is considered weird as from time to time she has visions of a demon who wants to possess her. Once the girl isn't considered "sick" anymore, the man who runs the institution (or whatever this house is) gives the heroine some money and lets her leave the house. The thing is - the girl is in fact possessed by a real demon of some sort.
The ending is very characteristic - a group of people try to exorcise the demon out of her, of course it turns out it's too difficult for them so they decide to kill the girl. There is a short conversation between the heroine and the demon (the demon in that scene looks exactly like the heroine) and the demon says something like "They will kill you. Just accept me, say yes and I will save you". And the girl, tied to a bed, actually says yes, touches the demons hand (who's lying right next to her) and murders all of the people who tried to exorcise the spirit out of her. The ending has quite the comedic effect if I may say so.
If I remember correctly, I saw this movie about 2-3 years ago, so it is definitely fresh. My assumption is that it's an american movie (as all of the actors were american)
P.S. You can actually ignore the beginning of the description, the ending is so characteristic that if you've seen the movie it should click instantly.

I wouldn't include your email in the question.  People can just leave and answer to this questions down below.  When you check back on this site, there will be a link you can click at the top if someone has answered your question. Very good description, though! You could add more detail:  approximate year it came out, and country it's probably from (US, China, India...).

You're looking for The Last Exorcism Part II from 2013.

Seventeen year-old Nell Margaret Sweetzer is found completely insane when trying to explain her possession by the demon called Abalam. After medical and psychological treatment, she is sent to the Deveraux transition house in New Orleans managed by Frank Merle, who helps her to start a new life.

It ends in the exact manner you've described (with her taking the demon's hand, then killing everyone). The sequel to The Last Exorcism. Here's the trailer:




@Kamil No problem, but don't forget to approve the answer (by clicking on the check mark next to it).
